# Printing a foreign text in a variable in a html generated by R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

In Rstudio interactive console, I can print store foreign characters in a variable and correctly print it the way I want.

```
> (korean_hello <- "안녕")
[1] "안녕"
```

But in the html file generated by `rmarkdown::render`, I get following.

```
(korean_hello <- "안녕")
## [1] "<U+C548><U+B155>"
```

That is, instead of the native characters, Unicode representation of the string is printed. How do you make it so that the generated html correctly prints what I want?

Below is my `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rsconnect_0.4.3 tools_3.3.1
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. When I knit a rmarkdown document containing a chunk with `korean_hello <- "안녕"; print(korean_hello)`, the character is properly displayed.

Comment: Please include your `sessionInfo()` in the post.

Comment: @Yihui added sessionInfo()

Comment: Alright, Windows, as expected. I'm afraid you have to change your system locale from English to Korean from the control panel.

Comment: @Yihui Thanks for the quick response. So is there's no way to do this at the `rmarkdown::render` level? The reason I want to believe so is that when the text is not in r chunk in the R markdown file, it renders perfectly fine.

Comment: Right. For R code chunk output, the multibyte characters on Windows cannot be rendered correctly unless you change the locale of your system. This is a known issue: https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/issues/59 (unfortunately this is hard to solve since it may need a fix in base R)